# Acer nitro 5 AMD Ryzen 5000 series Brightness problem in 20.04 Lts ubuntu

Tags: brightness, acer

Can anyone please help me to solve the brightness problem.I. can't change brightness in ubuntu 20.04 ubuntu. It's always in full brightness.Please anyone help me.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to explain what the problem is? The screen is too bright? Not bright enough? You cannot change the brightness via the keyboard commands? The brightness cannot be set via display settings? A little more specificity will save everyone a lot of time providing solutions to a problem you may not have ... 

Comment: Are you on a livecd or is Ubuntu installed on your computer ? On a livecd with some driver you can't change your screen brightness.

Comment: Bascically i am on ubuntu with alongside windows 10 dual boot